# Chart.js not stacking chart

Tags: vue.js, chart.js

I'm trying to make a stacked chart with vue-chart-3/chart.js. I want a  chart like this one:

[image]

But I don't know for sure what I did wrong, the chart that I create is stacking the bars side by side:

[image]

chartData:

> {
> "labels": [
> "2020-10",
> "2020-11",
> "2023-04",
> "2023-05",
> "2023-06",
> "2023-07"
> ],
> "datasets": [
> {
> "label": "above_120",
> "data": [
> 0,
> 0,
> 0,
> 0,
>
> ```
>       7.9597462909733085,
>       10.92147729254032,
>       12.128219538943902,
>       13.092781081826708,
>       16.982628499580606,
>       17.622395653806972,
>       36.51382339697158,
>       45.423623102032764,
>       58.474440088803384
>     ],
>     "backgroundColor": "#1E5662",
>     "stack": "stackabove_120"
>   },
>   {
>     "label": "up_to_120",
>     "data": [
>       0,
>       0,
>   
>       15.875881135502462,
>       3.165108353314404
>     ],
>     "backgroundColor": "#3E300D",
>     "stack": "stackup_to_120"
>   },
>   {
>     "label": "up_to_90",
>     "data": [
>       0,
>       0,
>       0,
>       0,
>       0,
>      
>       6.197500821665821,
>       8.2908889492772
>     ],
>     "backgroundColor": "#DBD383",
>     "stack": "stackup_to_90"
>   },
>   {
>     "label": "up_to_60",
>     "data": [
>       0,
>       0,
>       0,
>       0,
>       0,
>       0,
>       1.5561216578540855,
>       0,
>       0,
>       0,
>       0,
>       0,
>       0,
>       3.376176540913938
>     ],
>     "backgroundColor": "#0A35AC",
>     "stack": "stackup_to_60"
>   },
>   {
>     "label": "up_to_30",
>     "data": [
>       0,
>       0,
>       11.186721091033386,
>       0,
>       0,
>       1.7895529268699548,
>       0,
>       0,
>       0,
>       0,
>       0.06295971365877787,
>     
>     ],
>     "backgroundColor": "#AE95B3",
>     "stack": "stackup_to_15"
>   }
> ]   }
> ```

I tried to use stacked: true

```
> const chartOptions = ref( {   scales: {
>     yAxes: [{
>       ticks: {
>         beginAtZero: true
>       },
>       stacked: true
>     }],
>     xAxes: [{
>       stacked: true,
>     }]   } } );
```

But it didn't work

complete component:

```
  <template>
  <div>
    <BarChart :chartData="barChartData" :chartOptions="chartOptions" />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { BarChart } from "vue-chart-3";
import { Chart, registerables, ChartData } from "chart.js";
Chart.register( ...registerables );

interface DataObject {
  label: string;
  data: {
    above_120: number;
    up_to_120: number;
    up_to_90: number;
    up_to_60: number;
    up_to_30: number;
    up_to_15: number;
  };
}

const props = defineProps( {
  data: {
    type: Array,
    required: true
  }
} );

const barChartData = ref<ChartData>( {
  labels: [],
  datasets: []
} );

handleChartData();

const chartOptions = ref( {
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true
      },
      stacked: true
    }],
    xAxes: [{
      stacked: true,
    }]
  }
} );

function handleChartData () {
  const chartData: Array<DataObject> = props.data;
  if ( chartData ) {
    const labels: Array<string> = [];
    const datasets: Array<ChartData> = [];

   
    const legendKeys = Object.keys( chartData[0].data );

    
    const dataArrays: { [key: string]: Array<number> } = {};
    for ( const key of legendKeys ) {
      dataArrays[key] = [];
    }


    for ( const dataObj of chartData ) {
      labels.push( dataObj.label );
      for ( const [key, value] of Object.entries( dataObj.data ) ) {
        dataArrays[key].push( value );
      }
    }


    for ( const key of legendKeys ) {
      datasets.push( {
        label: key,
        data: dataArrays[key],
        backgroundColor: randomColor(),
        stack: `stack${key}`
      } );
    }

    barChartData.value = {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: datasets
    };
  }
}

function randomColor () {
  const letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  let color = '#';
  for ( let i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
    color += letters[Math.floor( Math.random() * 16 )];
  }
  return color;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if vue-chart-3/chart.js is different, but according to chart.js your keys are incorrect under options.scales.  Instead of xAxes and yAxes, have you tried just x and y?

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#stacked-bar-chart

```
    chartOptions = {
        scales: {
            x: {
                stacked: true
            },
            y: {
                stacked: true
            }
        }
    }
```